# Swift how to open specific viewcontroller from today extension when main app is not open

Tags: ios, swift, today-extension, uiscenedelegate

I have created a today extension with some UIButtons and I want to open a specific view controller when the user taps a button. It works right now when the main app is open, but when it is closed then it will only open the main app and dont navigate to my specific view controller.

What I have done:
I have set up the URL Sheme and wrote the OpenURL Code if button is pressed in **TodayExtension View Controller**.

```
    @objc func buttonClick(sender: UIButton) {
        let tag = sender.tag
        if let url = URL(string: "OpenURL://\(tag)")
            {
                self.extensionContext?.open(url, completionHandler: nil)
            }
        }
```

In **SceneDelegate** I wrote the code to navigate to specific view controller in `func scene(_ scene: UIScene, openURLContexts URLContexts: Set<UIOpenURLContext>) {`

```
    func scene(_ scene: UIScene, openURLContexts URLContexts: Set<UIOpenURLContext>) {

    if let url = URLContexts.first?.url {

        if url.scheme == "OpenURL" {
            
        guard let rootViewController = (UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes.first?.delegate as? SceneDelegate)?.window?.rootViewController else {
                return
        }

        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Groups", bundle: nil)

        if  let rootVC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Create") as? CreateSingleGroupViewController,
            let tabBarController = rootViewController as? UITabBarController,
            let navController = tabBarController.selectedViewController as? UINavigationController {
                    navController.pushViewController(rootVC, animated: true)
            
            rootVC.buttonTag = Int(url.host!)
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

But like i said this only works when the main app is opened before.
What do I have to do that this works even if the main ap is closed?

With the help from Google I figured out that I have to set up the `func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {` function but I dont know how. What I have wrote is

```
    func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
        guard let _ = (scene as? UIWindowScene) else { return }
        self.scene(scene, openURLContexts: connectionOptions.urlContexts)

    }
```

but this dont work.

Hope someone can help me.

Answer (score 2):

Finally I solved my problem.

I had to add a line in scene willConnectTo.. function:

```
    func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {

        guard let _ = (scene as? UIWindowScene) else { return }
        
        if let url = connectionOptions.urlContexts.first?.url {
            UIApplication.shared.open(url)
            self.scene(scene, openURLContexts: connectionOptions.urlContexts)

        }
    }
```

Comment: Hi @Mina! Nice question and reply, can you add the hole snippet code in the solution please!

Comment: Hi @wazowski! I'm sorry but i have posted all the code I am using right now. The only thing I had added to the code from the question was the `if let url = connectionOptions.urlContexts.first?.url {
            UIApplication.shared.open(url)` line which you can see in my answer. Hope this will help you anyway!